# Fabric take long time with ssh

Tags: deployment, ssh, fabric, paramiko

I am running fabric to automate deployment. It is painfully slow.

My local environment:

```
(somenv)bob@sh ~/code/somenv/somenv/fabfile $  > uname -a
Darwin sh.local 12.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.4.0: Wed May  1 17:57:12 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.24.15~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

My fab file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import logging
import paramiko as ssh
from fabric.api import env, run

env.hosts = [ 'examplesite']
env.use_ssh_config = True
#env.forward_agent = True
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
ssh.util.log_to_file('/tmp/paramiko.log')

def uptime():
  run('uptime')
```

Here is the portion of the debug logs:

```
(somenv)bob@sh ~/code/somenv/somenv/fabfile $  > date;fab -f /Users/bob/code/somenv/somenv/fabfile/pefabfile.py uptime
Sun Aug 11 22:25:03 EDT 2013
[examplesite] Executing task 'uptime'
[examplesite] run: uptime
DEB [20130811-22:25:23.610] thr=1   paramiko.transport: starting thread (client mode): 0x13e4650L
INF [20130811-22:25:23.630] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_5.9p1)
DEB [20130811-22:25:23.641] thr=1   paramiko.transport: kex algos:['ecdh-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', 'diffie-hellman-grou
```

It takes 20 seconds before paramiko is even starting the thread. Surely, `Executing task 'uptime'` does not take that long. I can manually log in through ssh, type in uptime, and exit in 5-6 seconds. I'd appreciate any help on how to extract mode debug information. I made the [changes mentioned here](http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/mac/fix_ssh_connection_delays), but no difference.

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
env.disable_known_hosts = True
```

See:
https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/pull/192
&
[Slow public key authentication with paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588535/slow-public-key-authentication-with-paramiko)

Comment: It works!!! My fabric program speeds up from tens of minutes to seconds!!
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a problem with DNS resolution and/or IPv6.

A few things you can try:

- replacing the server name by its IP address in `env.hosts`
- disabling IPv6
- use another DNS server (e.g. OpenDNS)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this post-2014, `paramiko`, which was the slow component when checking known hosts, introduced a fix in March 2014 (v1.13), which was allowed as requirement by `Fabric` in v1.9.0, and backported to v1.8.4 and v1.7.4.

So, upgrade !